# Paypal IPN Simulator not allowing for GBP?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using a paypal simulator to test my IPN page. But the drop down menu only allows for USD, my first check in my IPN is to make sure that the payment method is GBP.

Any workarounds?

I'm getting:

```
IPN was sent and the handshake was verified.
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently only `USD` is supported in [IPN simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/)
If you want to use GBP, you can test using your button code.

Eg :

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXX.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value=<YOUR_IPN_FILE>
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```